# Displaying PDF file with Adobe Reader

Tags: android, file, pdf, arrays

I created a class openPDF which takes a byte array as input and displays the PDF file with Adobe Reader. Code:

```
private void openPDF(byte[] PDFByteArray) {


    try {
        // create temp file that will hold byte array
        File tempPDF = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf", getCacheDir());
        tempPDF.deleteOnExit();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempPDF);
        fos.write(PDFByteArray);
        fos.close();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempPDF);
           intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);     

           startActivity(intent);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String s = ex.toString();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I pass the intend , the error from adobe reader is "Invalid file path". I read all other posts related to downloading and viewing PDF in android but dint help much. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried having a not temporary file as input to the adobe app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this code to open an especific .pdf file existing in Dowloads folder with Adobe's application

```
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
    File pdf = new File(folder, "Test.pdf");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdf);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

It works for me. So i guess your problem can be the temprorary file. Try to write the file to sdcard. To do this you will need add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that other apps have no access to the files in your app's private data area (like the cache dir).

Candidate solutions:

1. changing the file's mode to MODE_WORLD_READABLE so that it can be read by other apps

   ```
   ...
   String fn = "temp.pdf";
   Context c = v.getContext();
   FileOutputStream fos = null;
   try {
       fos = c.openFileOutput(fn, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       fos.write(PDFByteArray);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // do something
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (fos!=null) {
           try {
               fos.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   String filename = c.getFilesDir() + File.separator + fn;
   File file = new File(filename);
   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);     
   startActivity(intent);
   ...
   ```
2. or write the pdf file to the /sdcard partition.

   you can use android.os.Environment API to get the path, and remember to add the permission to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

Regards

Ziteng Chen